# Loading textfile with JSON file pathnames and trying to see where JSON is invalid and in which filename

Tags: python, json, text-files

So I am loading in a textfile with many different JSON file pathnames. There will be some instances where the JSON format might be invalid. I figured out a way to check if a file has invalid JSON, but I need it to display which specific file name is incorrect. Here is what my code looks like:

```
def openfile():
    user_path= input("Please input file name:")
    with open(user_path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            strip= line.rstrip()
            with open(strip, 'r') as x:
                alpha = x.read()
                try:
                    jObject = json.loads(alpha)
                except ValueError as e:
                    print("There is invalid json %s" % e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
jsonparse()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your code assumes there is one json object per line and you are already getting the filename as an input ... are you looking for the line numbers that fail?

Comment: Just print your `strip` variable in the error message. That holds the name of the file.

Comment: `print("File:%s, is invalid json %s" % (strp, e))`